# How to queue requests until the function returns a response for a previous request?

Tags: python, discord.py

When the user sends !bot  in a special channel, the code runs a function that runs for 20-30 seconds (depends on some_var). My problem is that if several people write !bot , the code will reverse this in multiple threads. How do I queue for these requests?

I tried to understand asyncio, discord.ext.tasks, but can't figure out how it works

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    data = args
    if data:
        answer = some_function(data[0]) #works from 5 seconds to 1 minute or more
        await ctx.send(answer)
```

Everything works well, but I just don't want to load the system so much, I need a loop to process requests first in - first out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `asyncio.Queue` to queue tasks, then process them sequentially in a background loop:

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

queue = asyncio.Queue()

bot = commands.Bot('!')

@tasks.loop(seconds=1.0)
async def executor():
    task = await queue.get()
    await task
    queue.task_done()

@executor.before_loop
async def before():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, num: int):
    await queue.put(helper(ctx, num))

async def helper(ctx, num):
    await asyncio.sleep(num)
    await ctx.send(num)

executor.start()
bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Well, thank you.
It works perfectly with your code, but my code have synchronous functions
I need to make them all async?

Comment: Yes.  If your bot blocks the event loop for too long, then the task the maintains the connection with the Discord backend won't run on schedule and Discord will terminate your connection.  What about your function takes so long to run? Could you do it in a separate process?

Comment: My bot checks the availability of shoes through the API of the web-site for the PID that the user enters. To make it all work quickly, I used multiprocessing, but now I want to rewrite my bot.

Comment: You should be able to write all of your web requests with `aiohttp` and do the asynchronously.  You already have aiohttp installed, since that's what discord.py uses to communicate with the backend.

Comment: Is there any way to thread queue tasks? I want to run a task with iterable argument and then work with results :)

Comment: Depends what you want to do. You should probably open a new question so you can go into more detail and show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Make `some_function()` to `async` then `await` it. Then all `test` command will be processed simultaneously.

```
async some_function(...):
    # something to do

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *args):
    if args:
        answer = await some_function(data[0])
        await ctx.send(answer)
```